# How can I extract td from html in bash?

Tags: html, regex, bash, shell, screen-scraping

I am querying London postcode data from geonames:

http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=london&country=GB

I want to turn the output into a list of just the postcode identifiers (Bethnal Green, Islington, etc.). What is the best way to extract just the names in bash?

Comment: Bash is the wrong tool for this job. Consider a perl, python or ruby script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean this `\n` delimited list (or one in brackets and comma delimited)

```
html='http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=london&country=GB'
wget -q "$html" -O - |
  w3m -dump -T 'text/html'|
    sed -nr 's/^ +[0-9]+ +(.*) +[A-Z]+[0-9]+ +United Kingdom.*/\1/p'
```

`w3m` is a: *"WWW browsable pager with excellent tables/frames support"*

output (first 10 lines)

```
London Bridge   
Kilburn         
Ealing          
Wandsworth      
Pimlico         
Kensington      
Leyton          
Leytonstone     
Plaistow        
Poplar
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the site offers (but not for free) web services with XML or JSON data... It would be the best way, since the HTML page is not meant to be parsed (easily).

Anyway, nothing is impossible, nonetheless using strictly only bash commands would be a lot hard, if not impossible; often several other common tools are piped in order to achieve the result. But then, sometimes it turns to be more conveniente to stick to a single tool like e.g. Perl, instead of combining cat, grep, awk, sed and whatever else.

Something like

```
sed -e 's/>/>\n/g' region.html |
   egrep -i "^\s*[A-Z]+[0-9]+</td>" |
   sed -e 's|</td>||g'
```

worked extracting 200 lines, assuming a specific format for the code.

**ADD**

If there's no limit to the software you can use to parse the data, then you could use a line like

```
wget -q "http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=london&country=GB" -O - |
     sgrep '"<table class=\"restable\"" .. "</table>"' | 
     sed -e 's|/tr>|/tr>\n|g; s|</td>\s*<td[^>]*>|;|g; s|</th>\s*<th[^>]*>|;|g; s|<[^>]\+>||g; s|;;&nbsp;.*$| |g' |
     grep -v "^\s*$" |
     tail -n+2 | cut -d";" -f2,3
```

which extracts places and postal codes seperated by a `;` like in a CSV, as well as awk:

```
wget -q "$html" -O - | 
     w3m -dump -T 'text/html' |
     awk '/\s*[0-9]+ / { print substr($0, 11, 16); }'
```

which is based on the answer by Peter.O and extracts the same data... and so on. But in these cases, since you are not limited to the minimal tools found on most Unix or GNU systems, I would stick to one single widespread tool, e.g. perl.

Comment: (and of course, this extracts postcode identifier, not places)

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is a mess. It's been said so many times, you should never try to parse html with regex.

Comment: @pguardiario you misunderstood the usage of regex: they are not used to do HTML parsing, in fact they are used to extract data hidden inside noise; in two solutions it happens the noise is HTML text, but it is an accident. Parsing is a really different act. I think you have a little bit of confusion about it.

Comment: and of course, trying to do complex stuffs in one-liner tends to become messy when you want to avoid "complex" tools like w3m. As said in the final part, if you can use "complex" programs, then it's better to stick to a language like perl (using perl, and appropriate modules, you can even *parse* the HTML, if you like)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `mojo` tool from the Mojolicious project this all becomes quite a lot easier:

```
mojo get 'http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=london&country=GB' '.restable > tr > td:nth-child(2)' text | grep ^'[a-zA-Z]'
```

The `grep` at the end is just to filter out some junk results; almost (but not quite) every other line is bad, because the page structure is slightly inconsistent. Otherwise you could say `tr:nth-child(even)` and get nice results.

Comment: Refenced in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360575/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-the-table#comment124377343_70360575)