# Outwit Hub - Markers and Lookahead maybe?

Tags: regex, parsing, web-scraping

Here is the code:

```
<div>23 Anywhere Ave<br />Someplace<br />Somewhere 1234</div>
```

I want to scrape the resulting three lines

```
23 Anywhere Ave<br />Someplace<br />Somewhere 1234</div>
```

into separate columns. I can scrape the first string (23 Anywhere Ave) by setting `<div>` as the front marker and `<br />` as the back marker. 
Get stuck after that. I've tried setting the front marker as `<div>(?=)<br />)`, `/<div>(?=)<br />)/` (Outwit apparently require / / when making a regex statement), and `<div>/(?=)/<br />)`to get the second value but no luck.

I realise that regex is not suitable for parsing HTML, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588389/regular-expression-to-extract-city-state-and-country-from-html) indicates that it's OK in certain contexts within the Outwit architecture.

Comment: Can you post a link to the source URL?

Comment: It appears previous correspondence on this question was deleted. Gave up and am now using Scrapy. Thanks for your interest anyway.

Comment: Check out what we're doing at http://www.import.io you may find it helpful.

Comment: @Andrew Fogg - I now use import.io, it covers what I wanted to achieve in the OP

Answer (score 0):

In automators/scrapers put this Separator: br
Then in List of Labels: Street,City,ZipCode

Br,
Eusebio.